# Can I control the order in which the components of a SplitView are loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to adapt an iPhone application for iPad using a second storyboard and a `UISplitViewController`. I'd like to reuse the iPhone viewcontrollers but the order in which the views have been called has been changed. How can I restrucutre the order in which the viewControllers are loaded and is the current order typical of how a `UISplitViewController` works?

**iPhone View Flow :**
TableView/MasterViewController > DetailViewController

**iPad View Flow:**
Detail ViewController > `TableView/MasterViewController` > `SplitViewController`

*The above is the order in which the `viewDidLoad()` method for these classes are called*.

[image]

**App Delegate file:**

```
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone){
       print("iPhone style UI")
}else{
           print("iPad style UI")
           IPAD = true
           var mainView: UIStoryboard!
           mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard2", bundle: nil)



           let splitViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initial") as! UISplitViewController

           let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
           masterSplitViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as! MainViewController
           detailSplitViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as! DetailsIpad
           detailSplitViewController.meeting = Meeting.init()
           self.window!.rootViewController = splitViewController

           //let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController

       }
```